# Data Generation for SQL Server in VS13

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have seen a couple of tutorials for the built-in "Data Generation Plan" template and from what I've seen it just throws in random data of the chosen data type.

I'm working with specific formats such as ISBN and Dewey Decimals for a table that keeps track of books.

Is there a way to set specific patterns for the test data such as an ISBN which would be something like 978-3-16-148410-0?

I'm not afraid to mention that this is my very first time ever trying to populate test data. Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated as I'm not the most seasoned of developers.

Comment: You may want to get rid of the "tool recommendation" part since that is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *custom data generator* in, for example C#. It'll available in dropdown list when you assign a generator for a column. First derive your your own `Generator` (in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Data.DataGenerator`):

```
public class IsbnGenerator : Generator
{
    [Output]
    public string Isbn
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    protected override void OnGenerateNextValues()
    {
        Isbn = "978-3-16-148410-0";
    }
}
```

Note that using `GeneratorStylesAttribute` you may specify which options your generator supports (for example unique values). Don't forget to strong sign your assembly and to [register it as a custom data generator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833152(v=vs.80)).

For a complete walkthrough read [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Data Generator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa833175(v=vs.80).aspx) in MSDN.